# Give users access to Set-Mailbox command to change -ProhibitSendReceiveQuota -Prohibit SendQuota and -IssueWarning in Exchange 2010

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange, exchange-2010, powershell

Is it possible to give users access to Set-Mailbox command to change `-ProhibitSendReceiveQuota` `-ProhibitSendQuota` and `-IssueWarning` parameters on every mailbox on Exchange server 2010 without giving full access to console ?

We want to give specific users the power to change the storage size on everyone's mailboxes from powershell but not much more besides that.

Is this possible?

p.s. I'm doing this from Windows Server 2008 with Exchange 2010 installed

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Look into RBAC. You can assign a role to a user or group. For what you're describing you would want to make a custom role : you do this by copying a role that looks like the one you will want to end up with, and then remove every cmdlet that you don't want them to have. It's a little inelegant to do it, but the end-product works.

Or you could just see if you're happy with using the existing roles out of the box and assign one of those.